# Proper Navigation Between Tabs in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Like the user in this thread [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67085933/simultaneously-use-tabbar-and-flyout-in-xamarin-forms), I wanted a Flyout menu but with tabbed navigation - so I added Tabs to my first Flyout Item. In my tabs, I want to use C# to navigate to other tabs - but when I do so with `await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabIWantToGoTo());`,  my app doesn't actually navigate to that next tab, it stays on the current tab and creates a new instance of that page within it.

My question is - how can I recreate the exact functionality of a user selecting a given tab? I want that tab have its tab icon highlighted and I don't want a separate instance with a back button on my current tab. Here are some images of the issue:

[Image of Tab 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0sj0.png)

[Image of Tab 2, navigated to via the above C# command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edGvc.png) - You'll see that Tab 1 is still selected and now there is a back button. I'd like, ideally for there to be no back button and for Tab 2 to be selected just like a user would expect when selecting Tab 2 by touch event.

[Image of Tab 2, selected by manual user input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3diY.png) - No back button, Tab 2 is properly highlighted and Tab 1 is now unhighlighted

Thanks!

Comment: set the `CurrentPage` property of the `TabbedPage`

Comment: I think the template project in VS2019 can do this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the images, your project is a shell app. So you can try to set the `Shell.Current.CurrentItem` in the page.cs. Such as:

In the AppShell.xaml:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png">
    <Tab Title="One">
       <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Two">
        <ShellContent Route="ItemsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

And then I go to the Items Page in the AboutPage.cs:

```
Shell.Current.CurrentItem = Shell.Current.Items[0].Items[1];
//the first Items is the FlyoutItems and the second Items is the Tabs in the FlyoutItems
//So this line code is go to page which is the first FlyoutItem's second shell content.
```

You can check the official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs#tab-selection

Comment: Does this solve your problem?@Anubis4574